# PHP issue reading huge data from txt files

Tags: php, readfile

I'm running a php script that reads from some pipe-delimited txt files, those files contain around 22,000 records. I'm using PHP file() function to read those files, BTW the files have some inter-relation too, I'm pasting the code here for better understanding

```
public function getGames()
{
    $resource = self::DATAFILES.'Product.txt';

    $games = array_slice($this->readFile($resource), 1); 
    $data = array();
    $count = 1;
    foreach($games as &$records)
    {
        $game = new Game();
        $attributes = explode($this->delimiter,$records);
        $game->api   =  (int) $attributes[0];
        $game->console_id = (string) $attributes[1];
        $game->title = (string) $this->getTitle($attributes[2]);
        $game->barcode = (string) $attributes[4];
        $game->image = $this->getCoverImage($attributes[0]);
        $game->releateDate = strtotime($attributes[8]);
        $data[] = $game;
        //if($count == 100): break; else: $count++; endif;
    }

    print '<pre>'; print_r($data); 


}

public function getTitle($titleID)
{
    $resource = self::DATAFILES.'Title.txt';

    $titles = array_slice($this->readFile($resource), 1); 

    foreach($titles as $records)
    {
        $attributes = explode($this->delimiter,$records);

        $pattern = '/^' . preg_quote($attributes[0], '/') . '$/';
        if (preg_match($pattern, $titleID))
        {
            return $attributes[2];
            break;
        }

    }

}

public function getCoverImage($gameID)
{
    $resource1 = self::DATAFILES.'ProductImage.txt';

    $coverImages = array_slice($this->readFile($resource1), 1); 

    foreach($coverImages as $img_records)
    {
        $image_attributes = explode($this->delimiter,$img_records);

        $pattern1 = '/^' . preg_quote($image_attributes[0], '/') . '$/';
        $pattern2 = '/^' . preg_quote($image_attributes[3], '/') . '$/';

        if (preg_match($pattern1, $gameID) && preg_match($pattern2, 'Cover'))
        {
            return $image_attributes[2];
            break;
        }

    }
```

So the problem I'm facing here is that - when I run that script it will just go on and on nothing happens i.e never throws any error neither print the returned array, however when I limit's the loop iteration up to 100 it works which means nothing wrong with the code so I thought perhaps, php script execution time making trouble so I changed it to max_execution_time = 0 - but still not getting the results. Any help or suggestion, would love hear that.. :)

BTW I'm using Xampp Apache for my local dev !

Comment: How long have you let the script run? I would put some sort of print or echo statement inside the foreach that prints out the title of the current game being added to $data. That way you can really see if the script is stopping execution or is just taking a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Well I let that script run upto even half an hour but it didn't output the result and just loading all the time, also I have changed memory_limit to -1, max_input_time to -1, max_execution_time to 0, but nothing works..